# QTableView external drag and drop

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qtableview

Is there a way to drag rows out of a QTableView?

I know how to internally move columns within a `QTableView` by configuring some properties on the view:

```
table_view_->horizontalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);
table_view_->horizontalHeader()->setDragEnabled(true);
table_view_->horizontalHeader()->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
```

Going through the documentation on `QAbstractItemView::DragDropMode`, I intuitively expected my following attempt to allow external dragging of vertical header items:

```
table_view_->verticalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);
table_view_->verticalHeader()->setDragEnabled(true);
table_view_->verticalHeader()->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragOnly);
```

Still, I am limited to only internal move.

Given [this article](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/model-view-dnd.html) I derived my own model from `QSqlRelationalTableModel` and added the `Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled` flag to the `flags` function, for all vertical header indexes:

```
Qt::ItemFlags MyRelationalTableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags defaultFlags = QSqlRelationalTableModel::flags(index);

    if(index.column() == -1 && index.row() > -1) {
        qDebug() << "drag enabled.";
        return Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | defaultFlags;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "not drag enabled.";
    }

    return defaultFlags;
}
```

This didn't change anything and given the debug prints, `flags` wasn't even called for vertical header items.

Comment: I wonder why I get down-voted on this question. If anyone thinks the question is stupid, than please point out my stupidity so I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding acceptDrops(true) to the QTableView help at all?

Comment: No, since `setAcceptDrops(bool on)` will only enable or disable drop on the QTableView. At this point I am only concerned with allowing the user to drag stuff out of the widget.

Comment: Try this out, especially the bit where they start the drag action. [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/dnd.html). You can install an event filter on the widgets that you expect the headers to be dropped onto and check for the sender?